# How to parse Java annotation in generic type?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
public @interface NotNull {}
```

And have a class:

```
class Main{
   List<@NotNull String> list;
}
```

How should i parse this annotation using Reflection API?

Comment: You're mixing up concepts here. `@NotNull` is an annotation but you're using it like a generic type. It should be `@NotNull List<String> list;`. Then you should be able to get the`Field` from `Main` fairly easily (have a look at the reflections api - it should be something like `Main.class.getDeclaredField("list")`) and get the annotation from the `Field` reference.

Comment: I use @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE), that means i can use this annotation inside generic type. In this case this annotation is not for list, it's for generic parameter.

Comment: @Thomas `@NotNull List<String> list;` means that `list` cannot be null, `List<@NotNull String> list;` means that `list` cannot ___contain___ null elements. That's nothing special in Java and usual validation libraries.

Comment: >means that list cannot contain null elements
Yes, this is what i wanted. My answer is how to parse this annotation, because `Main.class.getDeclaredField("list")` will not work.

Comment: Ah I see, never used that tbh.This might help then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164461/how-to-process-annotations-with-targetelementtype-type-use

Comment: There annotation processor implementing is used, i need to do it with pure reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation shows up *within* the generics part. This immediately means two things:

1. If the type is in a place that isn't part of a signature (so, a local variable declaration, or a cast, or the X in `new Foo<X>()`, etc - then **it is just gone**, generics are erased in such circumstances. There is simply no way to refer to it, you can't see it anymore at runtime.
2. If the type *is* part of a signature (it is the type of a field, the return type of a method, the type of a parameter, or something you `extends` or `implements`), then it is retained at runtime, but, all the usual methods to get this stuff, such as `someJLReflectFieldInstance.getType()`, always return a `java.lang.Class` instance, and generics is eliminated from these as well, so you can't use these methods.

If you're in boat #1, the answer is immediately over: *impossible*.

If you're in boat #2, this is possible. First, find the `getGenericType()` method - a variant method that also returns the type you want, but as a `Type` and not as a `Class`. For `j.l.reflect.Field`, that method is `getGenericType()`. Similar methods exist for method return types, parameter types, etcetera. Then realize this still isn't enough - that gets you the stuff in the `<>`, but strips out all annotations. Keep looking and you find the true winner. For `j.l.r.Field`, that is `getAnnotatedType`.

You now have an `AnnotatedType`, which seems almost entirely useless: It has virtually no methods. It's a catch-all marker-esque interface, because there are really different ideas on what types are in java. `?` is a type in this sense, because it can show up in a place types show up: `List<?>`. So is `? extends Map<?, Set<String>>`. So is `T`, and so is `String`, and so is `int[]`, and so `double`. And they can almost all be annotated.

The usual solution is casting and `instanceof` checks. Something like `List<@NonNull String>` is a `java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedParameterizedType`. So let's cast and continue with that. This interface has the `getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()` method, which returns an array of that useless `AnnotatedType` again: Appropriate; after all, it could be `List<?>`, `List<String>`, `List<T>`, `List<? extends Stuff>`, etcetera.

`@NonNull String` would be an instanceof `java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType`.

Let's put it all together. Toss this in a file, compile it, and run it:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface NonNull {}

class Test {
        List<@NonNull String> example;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Field f = Test.class.getDeclaredField("example");
                AnnotatedParameterizedType listType =
                  (AnnotatedParameterizedType) f.getAnnotatedType();
                AnnotatedType annType = (AnnotatedType) 
                  listType.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
                for (Annotation ann : annType.getAnnotations()) {
                        System.out.println("Annotation found: " + ann);
                }
        }
}


javac Test.java; java Test
> Annotation found: @NonNull()
```

NB: If you know what you are looking for, the above isn't so bad, but if you're trying to process a wide array (heh) of possible type kinds, you soon run into a gigantic soupy mess of code. I'm not directly aware of libraries to help out, but you may want to look into it or write something; it's not too difficult to set up a visitor pattern for this stuff.

Comment: The question should mention `TYPE_USE` in the title, so it's easier to find.